# Change Storage Engine to WiredTiger for data from mongo backup

Tags: mongodb, storage-engines, mongodb-mms

we are running mongodb 2.6.1 and we would like to upgrade to 3.*

My question is that since we need to change storage engine can we do it with files that come from mongodb backup, instead of making mongodump/mongorestore (as it says in [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/#change-storage-engine-to-wiredtiger))?

Comment: This is an administration question, not a development question. I nominated it for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com. Also, what kind of backup are you talking about? There are several methods to backup MongoDB databases.